# Dynamic import in Jsonnet

Tags: dynamic, command-line-arguments, jsonnet

I want to get input file in Jsonnet so the following is working great for me:

```
local input          = import './inputfile.json';
```

Problem is that I want to pass the file name through the Jsonnet CLI and I tried to use --ext-str or TLA but in both cases im getting the following error:

```
computed imports are not allowed.
```

I also tried to use --ext-code like here:

```
jsonnet -J grafonnet-lib --ext-code input=(import "./inputfile.json") createDash.jsonnet
```

but then I'm getting:

```
zsh: unknown file attribute: i
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing zsh is gobbling up either the parenthesis or the double quotes. Drop both between single quotes.

```
➜  tmp jsonnet -J grafonnet-lib --ext-code input='(import "./inputfile.json")' createDash.jsonnet

{ }
```